# how to start bash in a directory in windows .bat?

Tags: git, bash, batch-file

OS:windows 10. I have to right-click a folder, choosing `Git Bash Here`. and get:

[image]

I have several folders to do. Now I want to get it done with .bat. How?

Currently I use this `start cmd /k "cd C:\Program Files\Git\bin && bash --login -i && cd /c/cloud"`, But `cd /c/cloud` doesn't work. I just get this:
[image]

Comment: it's consider bad form in StackOverflow Qs to post screen shots unless absolutely necessary. These are unreadable and generally, it makes it difficult for experts to search for expected text.  Just edit your Q, remove the screen shots and replace with copy/paste of the relevant text.Use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box on highlighted text to format as code/data/output. Good Luck.

Comment: Also, as you are attempting to improve your Q, please remove the old Q on the same topic (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36452261/how-to-start-a-folder-in-gitbash-from-a-bat-file). Good luck.

Comment: So by running the command you want the batch file to start?

Comment: I disagree with closing this question as duplicate. The suggested question doesn't have an accepted answer and also doesn't answer this specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `cd` parameter for git-bash.exe:

`"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" --cd=D:\mozdev`

This will open the Git Bash in folder "D:\mozdev".